# Python 3 segmentation fault on OS X Mavericks

Tags: python-3.x, osx-mavericks

I have been experiencing segmentation faults when using Python 3 on OS X Mavericks. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

I have tried to reinstall the package from the Python site, but this is ineffective. How would one recompile Python 3 on the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.3/

you can follow the instructions on the main python page for a quick and permanent fix.
cheers,

Answer (score 9):

This problem exists because of this bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue18458.

Basically, Python has code in Modules/readline.c that contains a workaround for a bug in libedit,  however the bug in libedit was fixed and Mavericks comes with the new version of libedit and the workaround now causes ython to segfault. The quick and dirty fix is to disable deadline processing by running the following command (from the bug document):

```
curl -O http://bugs.python.org/file32324/patch_readline_issue_18458.sh
openssl sha1 patch_readline_issue_18458.sh
# the digest should be 7cb0ff57820a027dd4ca242eb2418930f8f46b4c
sudo sh ./patch_readline_issue_18458.sh
```

Comment: sorry i did but I must of accidentally hit delete. My apologies and thank you for editing it.